# Convex set containing $8$ vertices of a hollow cube in $R^{3}$?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the smallest convex set containing $8$ vertices of a hollow cube in $R^{3}$?

Comment: The cube itself

Comment: Can you please justify this termenology? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

$\{\sum_{i=1}^{8} \lambda_i v_i | \lambda_i \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{8} \lambda_i=1\}$, where $v_i$ are the vertices of the hollow cube.